# Lucene and forward slash

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, special-characters

In my index there is a value companyName:opel/vauxhall
Searching for "opel/vauxhall" returns the correct results.
Searching for "opel/*" returns nothing.

Currently I'm replacing the '/' with spaces. But that does give my code a bit of a smell.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This kind of problem is almost always caused by the analyzer used for indexing and searching (parsing the query).

Try using a different analyzer, for example StopAnalyzer.